# Python: Using arrays as input for arrays

Tags: python

I'm trying to find all the local minima and maxima for each 24h period over a year. So what I'm trying to do is select one 24h set out of the whole year, find the extreme values and their indices and then refer to those values using the indices. However, I can't figure out the proper way to refer to the values, as there seem to be problems with data types.

Here is a minimal working example, with only one day of data.

```
spot_price = np.array([46.6 ,  41.33,  42.18,  44.37,  37.67,  39.7 ,  40.59,  43.26,
                       49.66,  65.48,  76.53,  83.63,  94.74,  94.02,  97.17, 101.27,
                       126.6, 149.97, 146.33, 140.28, 121.88, 102.61,  97.46,  85.16])

day = 1
day_hours = range((day-1)*24,(day)*24)
maxima = argrelextrema(spot_price[day_hours], np.greater)
minima = argrelextrema(spot_price[day_hours], np.less)
```

So now the values for maxima are [ 3 12 17], which correctly indicate the maximum values within the spot_price array's daily slice. However, I can't get the values out correctly. With the commands I tried, I'm getting these errors:

spot_price[day_hours[maxima]]
TypeError: range indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

spot_price[day_hours[maxima[0]]]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

So, how can I select the specific indices from day_hours so that I can get the maximum values out of the spot_price array?

Comment: Is `maxima` the array `[3 12 17]`, or is it a tuple containing the array, i.e. `([3 12 17],)` ? The docs suggest a tuple: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html - *"Note that the return value is a tuple even when data is 1-D."*

Comment: `spot_price[day_hours][maxima]`.